# Add blank rows to transposed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Goal: Insert blank rows in between rows.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'revenue_month': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'],
        'new_invoice_net': [1000, 2000, 3000],
        'new_accrual': [500, 1000, 1500],
        'tax': [100, 200, 300],
        'total_new_invoice_gross': [1500, 2500, 3500],
        'total_new_invoice_net': [1200, 2200, 3200],
        'reversal_of_accruals': [200, 400, 600],
        'new_revenue': [900, 1800, 2700],
        'net_revenue_in_period': [800, 1600, 2400],
        'change_in_net_revenue': [100, 200, 300],
        'total_accruals': [600, 1200, 1800],
        'settlement': [300, 600, 900],
        'account_revenue': [500, 1000, 1500],
    }
)

df_transposed = df.set_index('revenue_month').transpose()
```

I want to transpose df based on revenue_month, and insert empty row between `total new invoice net` and
`reversal of accruals` and between `change in net revenue` and `total accruals`.

This code below returns `KeyError`:

```py
# determine the row indices where you want to insert empty rows
    row_indices = [transposed_df.index.get_loc('total_new_invoice_net')+1,
                   transposed_df.index.get_loc('reversal_of_accruals'),
                   transposed_df.index.get_loc('change_in_net_revenue')+1,
                   transposed_df.index.get_loc('total_accruals(eom)')]

    for row_index in reversed(row_indices):
        transposed_df = pd.concat(
        [
            transposed_df.iloc[: row_index, :],
            pd.DataFrame(data=[[''] * len(transposed_df.columns)], index=[''], columns=transposed_df.columns),
            transposed_df.iloc[row_index :, :],
        ]
    )

# print the transposed DataFrame with empty rows
print(df_transposed)
```

Final output:
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```py
df_transposed.columns.get_loc('total_new_invoice_net')
```

will raise a `KeyError` since `total_new_invoice_net` is not a column of `df_transposed` but an index. It is a column of `df`. You have to index your rows, not your columns. I would also start from the last row and go backwards to avoid having to use `+ i`. It makes the code more readable. And some cleanup, gives you this:

```py
rows_to_be_followed_by_empty_row = [
    'total_new_invoice_net',
    'change_in_net_revenue',
]

row_indices = [df_transposed.index.get_loc(row) + 1 for row in rows_to_be_followed_by_empty_row]

an_empty_row = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[''] * len(df_transposed.columns)],
    index=[''],
    columns=df_transposed.columns,
)

for idx in reversed(row_indices):
    df_transposed = pd.concat(
        [
            df_transposed.iloc[:idx, :],
            an_empty_row,
            df_transposed.iloc[idx:, :],
        ]
    )
```

Comment: ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index([None], dtype='object')

Comment: Yes, I said "to start with".

Comment: thanks Filip, the solution you provided earlier seems to be closer to what I expect than the current one. I have made edit to the new updated solution, which has 2 blank rows instead of one, but in-between the right rows (between Total New Invoice Net
and Reversal of Accruals) and (between Change in net revenue and Total Accurals (EoM)).

Comment: @Luc Okey, but then you can just remove two of the indices. You only have to list the rows that you want to be followed by an empty row.